# Starting and stopping while loop in python

Tags: python

I need some help with starting and stopping the loop in this grocery list. I need to be able to pick a few items add the totals and tax, then give the user the option to end. I have included the deposit or tax separate as it would on a real check. Then you will get a grand total at the end. If you see any other errors please feel free to let me know. Thank you

```
#Welcome user to user display product and prices
print("Hello, welcome to the store")
print("This is the list & products")
print("0,Milk,$2.39/Gallon")
print("2,Eggs,$1.58/per dozen")
print("4,Water,$1.00/Bottle+$.05 deposit")
print("6,Soda,$.99/Can+$.05 deposit")
print("8,Bread,$2.99/Loaf")
print("10,Chips,$1.30/Bag")
print("12,Tomato,$1.99/Pound")
print("Ready-food box,$8.99/Box+$.0625 tax")

#Prompt users for his product
totalpurchase=0
wdeposit=.05
sdeposit=.05
rtax=.0625
gtotal=0
totwdeposit=0
totsdeposit=0
totrtax=0
while 0:
    choice=int(input("Enter your product code"))
if choice==0:
           qofmilk=int(input("How many gallons do you wish to purchase?"))
           totmilk=qofmilk*2.39
           print("Your total price for milk is", totmilk)
           totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totmilk
if choice==2:
            qofeggs=int(input("How many dozen of eggs do you wish to purchase?"))
            toteggs=qofeggs*1.58
            print("Your total price for eggs is", toteggs)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+toteggs
if choice==4:
            qofwater=int(input("How many bottles of water do you wish to purchase?"))
            totwater=qofwater*1.00
            print("Your total price for water is", totwater)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totwater
if choice==6:
            qofsoda=int(input("How many cans of soda do you wish to purchase?"))
            totsoda=qofsoda*.99
            print("Your total price for soda is", totsoda)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totsoda
if choice==8:
            qofbread=int(input("How many loafs of bread do you wish to purchase?"))
            totbread=qofbread*2.99
            print("Your total price for bread is", totbread)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totbread
if choice==10:
            qofchips=int(input("How many bags of chips do you wish to purchase?"))
            totchips=qofchips*1.30
            print("Your total price for chips is", totchips)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totchips
if choice==12:
            qoftomato=int(input("How many pounds of tomatoes do you wish to purchase?"))
            tottomato=qoftomato*1.99
            print ("Your total price for tomatoes is", tottomato)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+tottomato
if choice==14:
            qofchicken=int(input("How man pounds of chicken do you wish to purchase?"))
            totchicken=qofchicken*2.99
            print("Your total price for chicken is", totchicken)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totchicken
if choice==16:
            qofready=int(input("How many boxes of ready-food boxes do you wish to purchase?"))
            totready=qofready*8.99
            print("Your total price for ready-food boxes is", qofready)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totready
print(totalpurchase)
if choice==4:
            wdeposit=wdeposit*1
            totwdeposit=wdeposit*qofwater
            print("deposit", totwdeposit)
if choice==6:
            sdeposit=sdeposit*1
            totsdeposit=sdeposit*qofsoda
            print("deposit", totsdeposit)
if choice==16:
            rtax=rtax*1
            totrtax=rtax*qofready
            print("tax", totrtax)
gtotal=totalpurchase+totwdeposit+totsdeposit+totrtax
print("Your grand total is", gtotal)

while 1:
    action=input("press any key if you like to purchase otherwise type end to finish")
    if action=="end":
        break
```

Comment: `while 0:` is a bad start. It won't enter the loop at all

Comment: `0` means False in case of boolean, Also you can use if-elif to remove confusion.

Comment: Your indentation is off.

Comment: `while 0:` means condition will evaluate to false. So your code will not enter the first while loop at all.

Comment: do you have any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: I would like the loop to keep running until the user says end

Comment: Use `while True:`.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl could you help explain the while true statement. I have never used one before. do I need to define anything?

Comment: `False`, `0`, `''`, `[]`, `()` and `{}` all evaluate as `False`, since they contain, or are, nothing. Anything else evaluates to `True`, so `while True:` is the simplest way of writing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a variable to end the loop and when the users wants to stop adding items, then set the variable to something else.

```
done = false
while done:
    if choice == 0: 
        ...
        (prompt user to continue)
        if user is done:
            done = true
```

Comment: so I changed my first loop to start with 1. I am now having trouble with the taxes and deposits being added into the grand total. I am also having troubles with the user being able to end

Comment: @MikeDocLevine `while True:` is more conventional.